# How do you commit changes to a Windows container including Environment variables such as PATH?

Tags: windows, docker, save, commit, desktop

I'm using a Windows container in Docker and I was trying to save the changes I made to it including the PATH environment variable. I already tried docker commit, save, export but nothing works.

Below are the steps that I did:

1. Load the container from the image.

   docker run --name base-react-container -it -v d:\Volumes\base-react-app:c:\app base-react
2. Modify the PATH Environment variable from iojs to nodejs.

   SET PATH=C:\Program Files\nodejs;
3. Exit interactive.

   exit
4. Docker commit.

   docker commit base-react-container base-react:latest
5. Remove the docker container.

   docker container rm base-react-container
6. Reload the container by doing step 1 again.
7. Check PATH variable.

   PATH

   PATH=C:\Program Files\iojs;

I also tried the combination of save, load and export but still the same.
My work around for this is running the container with the -e switch but personally, it's kind of 'dirty' to me.
Here's my work around:

```
    docker run --name base-react-container -it -v d:\Volumes\base-react-app:c:\app base-react \
-e PATH='C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\npm'
```

I hope there's a way to save it all including Environment variables in an image.

Edit: Even my workaround did not work. :(.

Comment: You probably need to write a Dockerfile to build your image; within that you can use the [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) directive to set environment variables.  I think Windows environment variables work like Unix ones, so the result of the `SET` command is lost as soon as the `docker run` shell exits, before you get to the `docker commit` command.  `docker commit` is rarely a best practice and I'd generally avoid it.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. Yup that was my last resort. I've wanted to use the existing image and not create one because of so much effort I did, so many layers in the image already but nothing works so I deleted my container and image and rebuilt a new one from Dockerfile. Then I used a combination of Run mkdir and ENV to set the new PATH.
`
RUN mkdir "C:\Program Files\nodejs\" 
ENV PATH="C:\Program Files\nodejs\:${PATH}"
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["nodejs/", "C:/Program Files/nodejs/"]`

Now it works! But still, if there was a way to not redo building a new image and container, I'd prefer that.